# Clean of local remote branches

Tags: git, github

I have deleted branches on github and did `git fetch` locally.

`git branch -a` still lists remote branches.

- do I have to remove local remote branches manually anyway?
- is there a way to do an automatic cleanup of local remote branches (if something is not present on github then remove local remote branch)?

Comment: Run `git fetch --prune` (or `git fetch origin --prune` or `git remote update origin --prune` or any of a number of similar varieties of command, all using `-p` or `--prune`).

Comment: I use an alias called "refresh-remote-branches": `git config --global alias.refresh-remote-branches "remote update origin --prune"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `git fetch origin --prune`. This will remove remote tracking branches that no longer exist in the remote repository.